# Ensuring a valid auth token is always available

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager

I've been trying to figure out how to authenticate users for my android app.  It is based on a website which already has a developed api, using JWT to authenticate.

I have come against the problem of refreshing tokens.  Let's say I want to fetch something from the API and I need the auth token for that.  I check my current auth token.  If it is expired, I need to get a new one using some sort of refresh token.

However, it seems like almost no matter how I think of trying to implement it, I run into a few problems:

1. I don't want the UI thread to wait while I get a new token
2. I would prefer that I don't have to explicitly check whether the token
   is there (and then refresh it) before making any API call

I've come up with one solution that solves #1 and at least minimizes the pain of #2.  I can have some sort of `getToken` method.  As an example, using JS style promises because they're easier for me to understand:

```
function getToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // Check for token, and return if valid.
    // Otherwise, go to the server and get a new one
    ...
    resolve(token)
  }
}

// When making an API call
getToken().then((token) => {
  // Call API
})
```

I think I can work this out so that the request will never be running on the UI thread, which solves #1, and as far as #2, it's at least bearable.

**My question is this:** is there a better way to do this?  It kind of seems like `AccountManager` might be able to handle this sort of thing for me, but the documentation for it is subpar at best, so I'm not sure how I would even implement it.  If `AccountManager` can do it and you know of a good tutorial for it, please comment with that.

Comment: In case the api returns an http error if you request using an expired token. Request using your current token ,in case of error is e.g "401 token expired". Request refreshed token. Repeat your request using your new refreshed token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a method `getToken` which either returns the current token or gets a new one (blocking).  With this strategy, I need to make sure that it never gets called from the UI thread.  I created a `Retrofit2` interceptor which calls `getToken`.  The benefit of this method is that I can just call my Retrofit methods without worrying about the token at all, and it checks for expiration and gets a new one as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A way to accomplish this is intercept a 401 status code and refresh token.

If you are using Volley, you can extend `Request` class and override `parseNetworkEror(VolleyError error)` method. If need be, schedule a Job which will refresh the token ([JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)) and trigger an event to communicate UI about the change ([EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)).

The following example is using OAuth authentication, but can be easily changed to implement JWT.

```
@Override
protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {

    if (getDataAccess().shouldRefreshToken(volleyError)) {

        if (!EventBus.getDefault().hasSubscriberForEvent(TokenRefreshedEvent.class)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }

        CSApplication app = CSApplication.getInstance();
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = app.getJobDispatcher(app.getApplicationContext());
        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(JobRefreshToken.class)
                .setTag("REFRESH_TOKEN")
                .setTrigger(Trigger.NOW)
                .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
                .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
                .build();

        int result = dispatcher.schedule(myJob);

        if (result == FirebaseJobDispatcher.SCHEDULE_RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            LogUtils.log(LogUtils.Type.JOB, GsonRequest.class, "Scheduling job refresh token");
        } else {
            LogUtils.log(LogUtils.Type.JOB, GsonRequest.class, "Error on schedule refresh token");
        }
    }

    return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
}

public boolean shouldRefreshToken(VolleyError error) {
    boolean shouldRefreshToken = error.networkResponse != null && error.networkResponse.statusCode == 401;

    if (shouldRefreshToken) {
        Map<String, String> headers = error.networkResponse.headers;

        if (headers.containsKey("WWW-Authenticate")) {
            String value = headers.get("WWW-Authenticate");

            boolean issuerInvalid = value.contains("The issuer is invalid");

            shouldRefreshToken = !issuerInvalid;

            if (issuerInvalid) {
                log(LogUtils.Type.VOLLEY, DataAccess.class, "Issuer do token é inválido");
            }
        }
    }

    return shouldRefreshToken;
}
```

Job Code

```
getDataAccess().refreshToken(getApplicationContext(), new VolleyCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new TokenRefreshedEvent(true));

            job.jobFinished(params, false);

            log(LogUtils.Type.JOB, JobRefreshToken.class, "Refresh Token job finished");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VolleyError error) {
            super.onError(error);

            EventBus.getDefault().post(new TokenRefreshedEvent(false));

            job.jobFinished(params, false);
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better if it could do the check before, so that I don't have to wait for a roundtrip when I can tell from the JWT that it's already expired.  I guess I could possibly override some other method in Volley's `Request`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's better check expiration before (or periodically). In that scenario above, there were a considerable amount of time between expirations, so that overload was almost imperceptible.